# How to populate treeview control with data from database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

This is my code:

```
While dr2.Read()
    Dim node = New TreeNode(dr2("chapterno").ToString)
    geo.Nodes("toc").Nodes.Add(node)
    node.Nodes.Add(dr2("lessonno").ToString)
End While
```

I have a database with two tables. one for the chapters and one for the lessons of each chapter. I want my `TreeView` to look like Chapter 1 (parent node) has Lesson 1, Lesson 2, etc.. as its child node. but when I run my code, it has too many chapter 1, each has one lesson in it. please help me. big thanks!

Comment: uhm, i'll explain my database maam/sir. i have the table for all the chapters. it has chapter numbers 1-8. and then another table for lessons. it is connected with the chapter table. the lesson table has lesson numbers 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 for chapter 1 and lesson 2.1, 2.2 etc for chapter 2. i want it to appear like i'll call the chapter 1, and then automatically it has the lessons under it as its child node. thanks a lot

Comment: So it's better to load `Chapters` table first and then try to add `Lessons`, but you can you it using the `Lessons` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but the concept is: You need to remember the last chapter added to your treeview and the node used. If the chapter is still the same then add only the lesson using the chapter node, if the chapter is different add a new chapter node and set the variables used to guard your loop to the last values

```
Dim node as TreeNode = Nothing
Dim lastChapter as String = String.Empty
While dr2.Read()
    Dim curChapter = dr2("chapterno").ToString
    if curChapter Is Nothing OrElse curChapter <> lastChapter Then
        node = New TreeNode(curChapter)
        lastChapter = curChapter
        geo.Nodes("toc").Nodes.Add(node)
    End If
    node.Nodes.Add(dr2("lessonno").ToString)
End While
```

Comment: Will probably have to add an `Else` onto that to then add the lessons. Also is the line `If curChapter Is Nothing` meant to read `if curChapter IsNot Nothing`?

Comment: i've tried your code sir but it has an error in calling the lastChapter. it says that it is used before it has been assigned a value

Comment: @ABCDE I have initialized the two variables before entering the loop. This should remove the compiler error

Comment: @Jinx88909 no, I want to check if the node is nothing because this means we are at the first loop and we need to start a new node (Well probably testing the curChapter is enough). Also I assume the else is wrong because every  row contains both the chapter and the lesson number so when the node (chapter) changes we need to add also the first lesson for this new chapter

Comment: No you're right my bad, brain slipped into 2nd gear.

Comment: @Steve thank you so much sir! you're so amazing! it worked.

Comment: sir i have a question again. i want to load the chapters even if no lesson is yet connected into it. i mean, i have 2 tables which is connected to each other. the chapter table and the lesson table. when the lesson table is emoty, i want that the chapter still loads. how can i sir?

Comment: @ABCDE I suggest to post a new question with details about your problem. This will attract more people than a now closed question and helps the site to get more focused questions and answers. (In particular describe how are defined your tables - the fields and the relationship between them)